# How can I get dates inserted whenever a checkbox is checked?

Tags: c#, javascript, vb.net

I have this on markup:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Printed">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" style ="font-weight:bold; " runat="server" CssClass="style26"></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate> 
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then this code behind

```
For Each r As GridViewRow In gridView1.Rows
 If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("myrec"), CheckBox).Checked Then
   lblMessaget.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
 End If
 Next
```

All  I am really trying to do is whenever a user clicks a checkbox to check it and clicks the Print Checked Item box, today's date is inserted into the Date Printed column of the row of the checked box.

I am doing something stupid and that's why this is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Although I am trying to do this with vb.net or c#, if anyone can help me do it with JavaScript, that would be great also.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function CheckBox_Click() {
            $('#' + '<%=gridView1.ClientID %>' + ' tr:has(:checkbox:checked)  td:nth-child(3) span').each(function () {
                $(this).attr("innerHTML", new Date());
            });

        }

</script>
```

Comment: Please don't use long pleading for help in your question titles. Use the space instead to word your question more clearly - people will notice that faster without the extraneous words, and you'll get help more quickly. Thanks. :-)

Comment: ok, thanks @Ken. It was an attempt to show the urgency and my frustration but your poitn is well taken.

Comment: are you able to call the function

Comment: @COLD, what function?

I tried the code above page_load() event.

I also tried it in button click. Nothing happens.

Comment: I mean the action supose to happen when you click a checkbox or box is already checked whet it loads

Comment: Oh,my apology @COLD. The action is supposed to happen after you click the checkbox. 

This way, when some other users wants to print documents, the users can see that checkbox(es) with date and time have already been printed and no need to print them again.

Comment: WOW, It is awfully difficult for me to accept as great as this forum is, it is difficult to find good help on weekends; only those telling you how to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make sure you have the right label. 
`lblMessaget` is always assigned, but you say:

> *...date is inserted into the Date Printed column **of the row** of the checked box.*

So you also need:

```
CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("row-specific-label"), Label).Text = DateTime.Now.ToString( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
```

// Edit:

You need to make sure that you use the right index for the cell. You need the cell of the label whatever this is.

Comment: of course that didn't work.

However, I was able to get this to atleast stick date into the label.

Issue is that that date is not persistent. When user moves to page 2, the date is wiped off. Any ideas how to persist the date?

I have update the jquery that makes it insert the date into the label.